# Does WebSphere Liberty send usage data to IBM?

Tags: licensing, websphere-liberty, usage-statistics, data-collection, privacy-policy

I'm wondering if WebSphere Liberty is collecting usage data and send it as anonymous data to IBM.

If yes,

- What kind of data is being collected and sent?
- Can I disable that?
- Is the sent data encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could find in the licenses related to collecting data is in the general [IBM Customer Agreement](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/sla/software_policies/):

> 11.1 Verification Process
>
> Licensee agrees to create, retain, and provide to IBM and its auditors
>   accurate written records, system tool outputs, and other system
>   information sufficient to provide auditable verification that
>   Licensee's use of all Programs is in compliance with the ILAN Program
>   Terms, including, without limitation, all of IBM's applicable
>   licensing and pricing qualification terms. Licensee is responsible for
>   1) ensuring that it does not exceed its Authorized Use, and 2)
>   remaining in compliance with ILAN Program Terms.
>
> **Upon reasonable notice**, IBM may verify Licensee's compliance with ILAN
>   Program Terms at all sites and for all environments in which Licensee
>   uses (for any purpose) Programs subject to ILAN Program Terms. Such
>   verification will be conducted in a manner that minimizes disruption
>   to Licensee's business, and **may be** conducted on Licensee's premises,
>   during normal business hours. IBM may use an independent auditor to
>   assist with such verification, provided IBM has a written
>   confidentiality agreement in place with such auditor.

So the "Upon reasonable notice" can mean many things. So I think legally they can collect these information if they ask your permission some how through license update or something like that.

The "may be conducted on Licensee's premises" doesn't eliminate the possibility of electronic data collection off premises.

So to put this together, **I don't think they are collecting anonymous data right now, but legally they can with the right notification.**

Comment: Since when 'on permises during business hours' means `electronically off permises'?? Very strange interpretation.

Comment: @Gas It does not mean that. But the usage of "may be" made the mentioned details after it, sounds like an example of the allowed actions. Unless there a clear statement eliminating the possibility of "electronically off premises", it stands as a valid option as long as there is a "reasonable notice". What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no usage data is sent to IBM unless you knowingly do so through a support ticket.